# Python hw assignment String is replacing values, instead of adding them onto string consecutively

Tags: python

The code for this program is supposed to take the base 10 number to the specified base and return a string corresponding to the digits for the number represented in the specified base with a space between each of the digits. So far everything works perfectly but the problem I'm having currently is that each value is being replaced in the list instead of actually adding them to the list one by one. Here is the code I currently have. The prints are for me to keep track of the output for the time being. Thanks for any help

```
def convert(num, base):

    results = ''
    if num < base:
        results.append(num)
        print(results)
    else:
        results.append(num % base)
        print(results)
        return convert(num // base, base)

def main():

    num, base = input("Enter a number and a base, seperated by a comma: ")
    num, base = int(num), int(base)
    convert(num, base)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Current output:

```
            9
            6
            7
```

Desired output:

```
9 6 7
```

Comment: As this is a recursive assignment, there can be no for/while loops.

Comment: did you try printing your results as `print(results, end="")`

Answer (score 0):

`results` is a local variable and will be re-initialized to `''` each time you call your `convert` function. Change the method signature to accept an optional `results` argument to prevent this from happening:

```
def convert(num, base, results=''):                  # Notice the optional argument
    if num < base:
        results = results + " " + str(num)
        print(results)
    else:
        results = results + " " + str(num % base)
        print(results)
        return convert(num // base, base, results)   # Notice how we pass the existing result variable
```

As a side note, strings (such as `results`) do not have an `append` method, either change it to string concatenation using `+`, use `.format()` statement, or change the type of the `results` variable to a list instead.

Comment: It has always messed me up when an assignment says to inherit certain variables as it gives me the misconception that I can't inherit any new variables. This helps a lot, thank you!